# replacing labels in ggplot axis (not manually)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this dataframe with this plot:

```
data.frame(id = factor(sample(1:103, 10000, replace=TRUE,
                              prob = sample(1:9/10, 103, replace=TRUE)), levels = 1:103),
                  year = factor(sample(1950:2019, 10000, replace=TRUE, 
                              prob=sample(1:9/10, 70, replace=TRUE)), levels=1950:2019)) %>% 
        unique() %>% arrange(id, year) %>% 
        mutate(flag = TRUE) %>% 
        complete(id, year, fill = list(flag = FALSE)) %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        mutate(order = sum(!flag)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(year, reorder(id, order), fill = flag)) + 
        geom_tile() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
     legend.position = "bottom")
```

I'm looking to change the Y axis for the `order` values in breaks of 10 or a nice-visual-break.

I have tried this so far:

```
scale_y_discrete(labels = order, breaks=seq(1, 103, 10)) +
scale_y_discrete(labels = order, breaks=c(1,30,60,90,103)) +
```

The objective of this is when looking at the plot you can see how many variables are there from bottom to top with reasonable breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert the y-variable to numeric. `ggplot` will set the breaks automatically for a numeric variable.

You can do this if you replace `reorder(id, order)` with `as.numeric(reorder(id, order))`.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Here's why it works:

The `id` variable (on the y-axis) is a factor. When you use `reorder(id, order)`, you change the order of the factor levels. When you convert to numeric, R uses the factor levels. Here's a short example showing what happens when you convert a factor to numeric:

```
> ff = as.factor(c(4,5,6,7))
> gg = reorder(ff, c(4,1,2,3))
> ff == gg
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

`ff` and `gg` are both factors, but `gg` has a different order to the factor levels.

```
> levels(ff)
[1] "4" "5" "6" "7"
> levels(gg)
[1] "5" "6" "7" "4"
```

When you convert each factor to numeric, you get different results for `ff` and `gg`:

```
> as.numeric(ff)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> as.numeric(gg)
[1] 4 1 2 3
```

When you convert `ff` to numeric, you convert 4->1, 5->2, etc. However, when you convert `gg` to numeric, you convert 5->1, 6->2, 7->3, and 8->4.

In your case, you're re-mapping the factor `id` into a numeric variable, based on the levels of the factor.

Comment: It works!, but why? When I'm using `as.numeric(reorder(id, order))` I'm converting to numeric the id values ordered, not the order variable values, right? So, how ggplot knows how to map with the id values and label the axis with the order variable values if I didn't "tell him" that?

Comment: I added an explanation above. I hope that helps!